# Excel VBA - Sum of 1 in workbook not equal to 1 in VBA

Tags: vba, excel-formula

As screenshot shows below. Variable sum is 1 but still I end up in the else statement. How come?

[image]

Edit:
Solution. Wrote code as below. Good enough precision, included as many 9's and 0's before Excel change to 1# which does not work either:

```
If sum > 0.999...99 and sum < 1.00...001 Then
```

Comment: Probably due to floating-point error.

Comment: try `If sum = 1# Then`

Comment: Protip: try to avoid posting screenshots of code - paste the actual code instead, it makes it much simpler for answerers to copy/paste into an answer.

Comment: Alternately you could use Round(),  IF ROUND(sum,0) = 1 Then